# Binding to a calculated property of a BindableProperty from code behind

Tags: c#, xamarin, refresh, code-behind, bindableproperty

In short, I have a custom control in Xamarin for which I defined a **BindableProperty**, which I would like to bind to the control's xaml **via a calculated property** in the code behind, but it always displays as null because the calculated property is evaluated when the BindableProperty didn't have a value yet, and afterward I am missing property changed notification logic. Which is the right way to do it?

**Long explanation for context**:

I am writing a custom control in Xamarin (which I named `TabbedLayout`). I intend to bind an array of Views to a BindableProperty of the control, like so:

```
<controls:TabbedLayout.TabContents>
  <x:Array Type="{x:Type View}">
    <Button Text="Hello world 1!"/>
    <Button Text="Hello world 2!"/>
    <Button Text="Hello world 3!"/>
    <Button Text="Hello world 4!"/>
    <Button Text="Hello world 5!"/>
  </x:Array>
</controls:TabbedLayout.TabContents>
```

To that effect I have defined a BindableProperty in the code behind the Control (TabbedLayout.xaml.cs):

```
public static readonly BindableProperty TabContentsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(TabContents),
    typeof(View[]),
    typeof(TabbedLayout),
    null,
    BindingMode.OneWay);

public View[] TabContents
{
    get => (View[])GetValue(TabContentsProperty);
    set => SetValue(TabContentsProperty, value);
}
```

However, from the control's xaml I wish to display only one of those Views. I have first defined a int property to control which is the selected index (with other parts of the control, let's assume that `int SelectedIndex = 0` and I wish to display the first element).

I have then created a calculated property like so:

```
public View DisplayedElement = TabContents?.ElementAt(SelectedIndex);
```

And I have bonded to it from the control's xaml like so:

```
<ContentView Content="{Binding DisplayedElement, Source={x:Reference TheControl}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

At this point, the ContentView displays empty because TabContents is still null.

From here, how would I update the view as soon as the BindableProperty value is set, the first time and every time it might be modified, to trigger a refresh of the bound DisplayedElement property?

Comment: Where is SelectedTabContent defined?

Comment: My code has different names for the variables, I just adjusted it for the question to make it more readable and forgot to rename that variable. Now it should be aligned in the question, thank you.

Comment: `DisplayedElement` is not a C# property.  Binding only works with public properties

Comment: Well, I know I can bind to it because it is public and the breakpoint is hit when debugging, the first time. But you made me realize that I did not create a calculated property, just a variable, since I am assigning it with "=" instead of defining "=>". For this reason all my attempts to notify the property changed were in vain, because the variable was already assigned, instead of taking the new value. I will test it out and answer back

Comment: You can check this document about [Create a bindable property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties?view=net-maui-8.0).